# Why is flex-basis not setting height of flex-items with flex-direction 'column'?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Each member div is a flex item and the flex-direction of the flex-container is set to column. If flex-basis operates on the main-axis and because the flex-container is set to column, why is flex-basis not manipulating the heights of the flex-items like I want them too?

If I want to manipulate their heights, I have to do it using the height property, but why can't I do it with the flex-basis property? Without setting an explicit height, the flex items overflow:

For example:
Height property with value of 65px: https://ibb.co/1RBdbby
Flex-basis property with same exact value (it doesn't have the same effect): https://ibb.co/t8K4HR3

Why is height working better here than the flex-basis property? I thought flex-basis would surely manipulate the height of flex-items when the flex-direction is set to column.

```css
/* NEW MEMBERS */ 
/* RECENT ACTIVITY */
.new-members, 
.recent-activity {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.member {
    height: 65px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.member-image {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 10%;
    max-width: 70px;
} 

/* RECENT ACTIVITY */
.date {
    margin-left: auto;
}
.arrow {
    content: "\27A4";
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<!-- NEW MEMBERS -->
<section class="new-members">
    <h2>New Members</h2>

    <div class="member">
        <img class="member-image" src="images/member-1.jpg" />
        <div class="member-info">
            <p>Victoria Chambers</p>
            <a href="mailto:webmaster@example.com">victoria@hotmail.com</a>
        </div>
        <p class="date">12/04/20</p>
    </div>

    <div class="member">
        <img class="member-image" src="images/member-2.jpg" />
        <div class="member-info">
            <p>Dale Byrd</p>
            <a href="mailto:webmaster@example.com">byrd@hotmail.com</a>
        </div>
        <p class="date">12/04/20</p>
    </div>

    <div class="member">
        <img class="member-image" src="images/member-3.jpg" />
        <div class="member-info">
            <p>Dawn Wood</p>
            <a href="mailto:webmaster@example.com">wood@hotmail.com</a>
        </div>
        <p class="date">12/04/20</p>
    </div>

    <div class="member">
        <img class="member-image" src="images/member-4.jpg" />
        <div class="member-info">
            <p>Dan Oliver</p>
            <a href="mailto:webmaster@example.com">oliver@hotmail.com</a>
        </div>
        <p class="date">12/04/20</p>
    </div> 

</section>


<!--RECENT ACTIVITY-->
<section class="recent-activity">

    <h2>Recent Activity</h2>

    <div class="member">
        <img class="member-image" src="images/member-1.jpg" />
        <div class="member-info">
            <p>Victoria Chambers commented on YourApp's SEO Tips</p>
            <p>4 hours</p>
        </div>
        <span class="arrow">&#10148;</span> 
    </div>

    <div class="member">
        <img class="member-image" src="images/member-2.jpg" />
        <div class="member-info">
            <p>Dale Byrd likes the post Facebook's Changes for 2016</p>
            <p>4 hours</p>
        </div>
        <span class="arrow">&#10148;</span> 
    </div>

    <div class="member">
        <img class="member-image" src="images/member-3.jpg" />
        <div class="member-info">
            <p>Dawn Wood commented on Facebook's Changes for 2016</p>
            <p>5 hours</p>
        </div>
        <span class="arrow">&#10148;</span>
    </div>

    <div class="member">
        <img class="member-image" src="images/member-4.jpg" />
        <div class="member-info">
            <p>Dan Oliver posted YourApp's SEO Tips</p>
            <p>1 Day</p>
        </div>
        <span class="arrow">&#10148;</span> 
    </div> 

</section>
```

Comment: you will need to make it grow to fill the container - .member {..flex: 1 0 65px}

Comment: Both `flex-basis` and `height` are doing the same thing in your code above. https://jsfiddle.net/drwsyoa9/